# Additional synchronization of CyclicBarrier

Tags: java, cyclicbarrier

My code is like:

```
  public class Test  {

final static CyclicBarrier CYCLIC_BARRIER = new CyclicBarrier(3, newRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Correctly three?Really?");
    }
});

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i <6 ; i++) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CYCLIC_BARRIER.await();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start(); } }
 }
```

Got some mess about threadsafe synchronizers. Some fairly simple code here, and I want to get output like: thread1,thread2,thread3 and the message from Runnable,
but it seems there is a race condition:

```
      Three threads? Really?
      Thread-4
      Three threads? Really?
      Thread-5
      Thread-2
      Thread-3
      Thread-1
      Thread-0
```

So,should I add reentrantlock or whatever to fix it?

Comment: "*So,should I add reentrantlock or whatever to fix it?*" - yes.

Comment: Sorry for newbie question, but which part should be locked here?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your concrete question.

Comment: I'd say it's a bad idea to use `CyclicBarrier` this way. Clearly this is a test, but the value of this test is zero. The `CyclicBarrier` works perfectly, but then you've put in printing, and presumably expected to see some deterministic pattern in what gets printed and when. Sure, you can pepper in locks and additional things, but then you have a complex piece of garbage.